# "WSO2" - Developer Studio Expression not editable

Tags: wso2, wso2-integration-studio

Downloaded eclipse juno and wso2 studio 3.2. I am trying to do quick start example and I cannot edit Expression.

I have also downloaded eclipse helios + wso2 studio package from your link, in this case helios always hangs up when creating workflow.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed before [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616862/wso2-business-process-bpel-error-in-gui-with-if-component/17677234#17677234) & [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547806/wso2-developer-studio-edit-properties-of-an-assign-activity/17563759#17563759).

To get rid from the editor hangs up, increase the memory allocation settings defined in eclipse.ini file.

Thanks

-Thilini